# Is there a way to read RAW and TIMESTAMP datatypes in oracle and export to Excel using JAVA CODE

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there a way to read the RAW[10 bytes] and TIMESTAMP[6] data types from Oracle DB and export to the Excel sheet using APACHE POI through JAVA code.

Basically i am trying to write the data in excel file using setCellValue() method.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code, and tell us where you got stuck?

Comment: For RAW data type, i have converted the data which i got from DB(Resultset) to Object and stored into byte array and again converted back to Object and written to cell.                                                                                                                               For Timestamp data type ,cell.setCellValue(new Date());CellStyle style1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
 style1.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat(
     "dd-mm-yyyy"));cell.setCellStyle(style1);

Comment: I am not able to post the code

Comment: Without any code, there's really not a lot that anyone is going to be able to do to help you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.. I am able to get an answer for my query.
I have converted my Object which i am getting from ResultSet to String and parsed it to a date in a desired format and write it to a cell in excel.

```
    if (valueObject != null) {
                    String dateString = String.valueOf(valueObject); 
                     String trimmed = dateString.substring(0, Math.min(dateString.length(), 19));
                     String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                     LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(trimmed,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern));
                     cell.setCellValue(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern)));
                }
```